# DirectorySearcher.Filter return Users with birthday of current month

Tags: c#, ldap

I am trying to find all users with AD that have a birthday in the current month. I want this to be dynamic but anyways. I'm new to querying ldap and I'm have trouble writing the string that will filter the search. Currently I am getting all of the users and then using LINQ to sort through the list of returned users but I thought I would try just return the users from the AD Search. Right now I have:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry entry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(_path, username, pwd);

System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(entry);

mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=user)");
```

I believe the guy running AD has their B-days stored simply as a string in the format MMDD i.e. 0508. I can't do anything about that (if there is a better way there's nothing I can do about it).

So what's the best way to approach this?

Additional code if needed:

```
     SortOption option = new SortOption("sAMAccountName", System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending);

        mySearcher.Sort = option;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable("Users");

        dtUsers.Columns.Add("userid");

        dtUsers.Columns.Add("name");

        dtUsers.Columns.Add("birthday");

        dtUsers.Columns.Add("anniversary");

        dtUsers.Constraints.Add("UniqueUserId", dtUsers.Columns["userid"], true);



        foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())

        {

        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry de1 = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry();

        DataRow drUser = dtUsers.NewRow();

        if (de1.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value != null && de1.Properties["name"].Value != null && de1.Properties["employeeBirthDate"].Value != null && de1.Properties["employeeHireDate"].Value != null)

        {



        drUser["userid"] = de1.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();

        drUser["name"] = de1.Properties["name"].Value.ToString();
        drUser["birthday"] = de1.Properties["employeeBirthDate"].Value.ToString();
        drUser["anniversary"] = de1.Properties["employeeHireDate"].Value.ToString();



        dtUsers.Rows.Add(drUser);

        }

    }

    ds.Tables.Add(dtUsers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int now = DateTime.Now.Month;
                string month;
                if (now < 10)
                {
                    month = "0" + now.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    month = now.ToString();
                }

mySearcher.Filter = ("(&(objectClass=user)(|(employeeHireDate=" + month + "*)(employeeBirthDate=" + month + "*)))");
```

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP client can use a `substring` search filter to restrict the entries that are returned to the search request. For example, the filter `(&(objectClass=user)(birthday=05*))` will return all entries that have an attribute `objectClass` of `user` and a `birthday` attribute with a value starting with `05`. If this method is used, the directory administrators should be informed ahead of time so that they can ensure that the birthday attribute is properly indexed.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)